# Javascript - Split string into a unknown number of strings

Tags: javascript, string

My problem today is that I'm retrieving different id's back from a query which are all being stored in a string, for example:

```
2345, 6042, 2043, 4053
```

What I now want is for each of the codes separated by the "," to get split into individual strings, so using the previous example:

```
result1 = 2345
result2 = 6042
result3 = 2043
result4 = 4053
```

My problem is that the amount of ID's can be a different amount at different times, sometimes there may only be 2 ID's or there could be 10.

I'm unsure how to use the split text method when the amount is unknown.

Any help with code to demonstrate would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks Shaun

Comment: [`str.split(',')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Comment: Share the code you tried...!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to know the number of elements to perform a split. You will simply get an array of all the new strings, with the length of the array dependent on the source string.

Using your example:

```
var text = "2345, 6042, 2043, 4053";
var items = text.split(', ');

// items will now be an array of 4 strings: ["2345", "6042", "2043", "4053"]
```

That is assuming there is always a comma and a space. If you are not sure that all the elements will separated by both, you should split on just the comma, and then trim the results, for example:

```
items = items.map(function(el){ return el.trim(); });
```

That would also be a good point to parse them into integers (assuming they always are, and you need to do maths on them at some point of course).

Comment: Thanks for your help, there will always be a comma and space so it worked perfectly, Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "2345, 6042, 2043, 4053";
var arr = str.split(",");
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  results.push("result" + i + " = " + arr[i].trim());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`split` can be made by RegExp too.

```
var ids = '124523, 23444, 23, 123, 5345, 534, 867';
var idArray = ids.split(/,\s?/);

idArray.forEach(function(id) {
  console.log(id);
});
```

http://jsbin.com/bebevija/3/edit

Answer (score 0):

try this logic bro you will store every value in array then you can get it also using loop

```
var xx = "2345, 6042, 2043, 4053";
var x = xx.split(",");
var result = new Array();
for( var ctr = 0; ctr < x.length; ctr++ ){
    result[ctr] = x[ctr];
}

for( var ctr = 0; ctr < result.length; ctr++ ){
    alert( result[ctr] );
}
```

Comment: What is the point of the separate `x` and `result` arrays? You could just do `result = xx.split(",")`

Answer (score 0):

For an undetermined number of variables, I recommend to store the data in the array.

```
var str = "2345, 6042, 2043, 4053";
var arr = str.split(/,\ ?/);
//checking
console.log(arr[0], arr[1]);
```

variable arr stores an array of strings with numbers.
If it is important for you to store data in variables, see the code below

```
var str = "2345, 6042, 2043, 4053";
var arr = str.split(/,\ ?/);
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  window['param'+i] = arr[i];
}
//checking
console.log(param0, param1);
```

created variables in the window object.
Or you can create your own object

```
var str = "2345, 6042, 2043, 4053";
    var arr = str.split(/,\ ?/);
    var myObj = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      myObj['param'+i] = arr[i];
    }
//checking
console.log(myObj.param0, myObj.param1);
```